# I need a Window CMD to loop through folders in a directory and execute a command on each one

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Normally I would have to call a command once per folder like this:

`processdata.cmd C:\data\10-2-2019-run1`

`processdata.cmd C:\data\10-2-2019-run2`

`processdata.cmd C:\data\10-2-2019-run3`

etc.

I want to write a for loop that will run that command once per folder and append the directory just like in the commands above

I don't want it to loop through sub-folders

The only folders there contain data, so I don't need it to exclude any folders or files.

Just a very simple For loop using windows CMD (preferably not powershell)

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

`for /D %G in ("c:\data\*") do processdata.cmd "%~fG"`

Comment: thnx, but I'm getting error: The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~fG"

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: I read this and added another % for batch file, still getting an error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049351/why-i-am-getting-the-following-usage-of-the-path-operator-in-batch-parameter-sub   do process.cmd "%~fG" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: I got it, for batch file had to `for /D %%G in ("c:\data\*") do processdata.cmd "%%G"`

Comment: Great!  Glad you were able to get it working.  You need one % if the command is issued from the command-line, two if used in a batch file.  The ~f I had between the % and the G is to substitute the full pathname of the folder, instead of just the folder name without the path.  But if you run the processdata.cmd from the folder containing the folders you want to operate upon, you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would have to call a command once per folder like this:

processdata.cmd C:\data\10-2-2019-run1

processdata.cmd C:\data\10-2-2019-run2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124336)