# Iterate through directories, execute exe on files, use folder name for resulting file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, pdf, cmd.exe

I have a folder containing magazines, whose pages are in JPEG image format.
Like so:

```
The_Camera_Craftsman_1955_Vol_l_Iss_2 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1955_Vol_l_Iss_3 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1955_Vol_l_Iss_4 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1955-03_Vol_l_Iss_l 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1969_-_1978_Vol_25_Index 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1969_-_1979_Vol_25_Index
The_Camera_Craftsman_1974_Vol_20_Index 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1975_Vol_21_Index 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1976_Vol_22_Index 
The_Camera_Craftsman_1977_Vol_23_Index
The_Camera_Craftsman_January-February_1956_Vol_l_Iss5
```

[image]

I have img2pdf.exe located in a separate folder. I wish to loop through all the folders, and execute [`img2pdf.exe`](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) inside them, for instance with the following arguments

```
img2pdf.exe *.jpeg -o ####.pdf
```

**But** #### is replaced with the current directory's file name through a Windows CMD **variable** etc. As you can see, I want the issue of the magazine (folder name) as the pdf file name.

### What I have found so far

I can execute img2pdf from a different directory as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903288/run-an-exe-from-a-different-directory), but all manual inputs etc including file name.

I can loop through folders and execute something as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1464557/i-need-a-window-cmd-to-loop-through-folders-in-a-directory-and-execute-a-command), but it fails to produce a .pdf in each folder. Instead, it produces a single 0kb .pdf file at the root directory. And I tried to get the current folder name as the pdf file name, but it didn't work, the file was simply called %~nxI.pdf:

```
for /D %G in ("F:\tempbatch\*") do "...\img2pdf.exe" *.jpg -o "%~nxI".pdf "%~fG"
```

So - any pointers?

Comment: Try using the full path for img2pdf so that you can work in your current folder

Comment: I did. The img2pdf location ends like so do "...\img2pdf.exe" and the commands outside of it. I still don't know how to use current folder name for the file though. Maybe you could write out what you mean in a command?

Comment: "[path]\img2pdf]"  "[path]\location"

Comment: Stephan- I was using a wildcard sorry. ...\tempbatch\*" I have edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: John- I'm still not sure what you mean.

Comment: `*.jpg` looks for files in the current working folder. I think you will have more success with `"%~fG\*.img"`

Comment: `the file was simply called %~nxI.pdf` . You have no `%I`, but `%G`

Comment: Stephan- the *.jpg is an img2pdf command, all the files are jpg anyway. https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf#usage Where do I add %I ?

Comment: I just full paths in a quotes around them because of spaces and some special characters

Comment: That's what I've been doing, otherwise issues yeah.

Comment: According to the site you cited, there is no `%I` and wildcards are not supported.

Comment: Can you confirm that a manual `"P:\ath to\img2pdf.exe" *.jpg -o "test.pdf"` works?

Comment: Yes- the following produced a valid pdf. This is the line copied from CMD F:\tempbatch\The_Camera_Craftsman__July-August_1957_Vol_3_Iss_3>"F:\book stuff\ocrmypdf copy folder (making)\img2pdf.exe
" *.jpg -o output.pdf . That's what I talked about in the post.

Comment: `cd /d "F:\tempbatch"` followed by `for /D %G in (*) do "F:\book stuff\ocrmypdf copy folder (making)\img2pdf.exe" *.jpg -o "%~nxG.pdf"` Still not sure, where your additional parameter comes from.

Comment: Stephan- that managed to produce correctly titled but still 0kb files at the root of the directory.

Comment: oh, sorry - `...img2pdf.exe" "%~fG\*.jpg" -o...` of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@echo off 

set "_img2pdf=F:\book stuff\ocrmypdf copy folder (making)\img2pdf.exe"

for /r "F:\tempbatch" /d %%i in (*)do "%_img2pdf%" "%%~dpnxi\*.jpg" -o "%%~dpnxi\%%~nxi.pdf"
```

---

**Obs.:** Using your **file/executable** [linked in the question](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf)!

Comment: Perfect, works nicely, thanks so much!